# Jest error Unexpected token ... (ES6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am getting the following error whenever I run jest in commandline:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

/Users/<USER>/<Project>/src/login/LoginAPI.js:13
        ...headers,
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

The code that it breaks on uses ES6 ellipses:

```
headers: {
    ...headers
},
```

This is what my .babelrc file looks like:

```
{ "presets":["env", "react"] }
```

And this is what I have in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "express-healthcheck": "^0.1.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.4",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "query-string": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.0.2",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "jest-cli": "^21.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js"],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "bower_components",
      "shared"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/yarn-cache/"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I think you need the object spread operator plugin.

Comment: This is not an ES6 feature you're using, object spread operator is not even in the language yet, only stage 3. You might be used to the jsx that allows it but it doesn't work by default in js

Comment: @Axnyff - Oh I thought it was part of ES6. So does that mean I need to add stage3 to my .babelrc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a specific babel preset for this syntax. [Check this preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
```

And then add this to your .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

You might want to add [stage-2](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) as it has more ES6 goodies.

**Note:** [Jest can read your `.babelrc` file](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/babel-jest/src/index.js#L29-L67)

Answer (score 3):

In babel 7, 
`babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` will report error: `SpreadProperty has been renamed to SpreadElement`.

So I use:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
```

and config .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to this I believe, this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/170)  should outline some of them. I would give this a try first:

```
 {
   "presets": ["es2015", "stage-3", "react"]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "schema-utils": "2.6.6" as "dependencies" in your package.json

```
"schema-utils": "2.6.6",
```