# Jest tests fail on spread operator

Tags: ecmascript-6, vuejs2, jestjs, babeljs, spread-syntax

```
<template>
  <!--
    // replaced @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" with
    // v-on="$listeners", need testing
    // see more here
    // http://blog.webf.zone/vue-js-considerations-and-tricks-fa7e0e4bb7bb
  -->
  <div>
    <label class="form-label">{{ getLabel | capitalize }}</label>
    <input
      v-tooltip="getTooltipContent"
      :bind="$attrs"
      :type="type"
      :value="value"
      :placeholder="getPlaceHolder"
      :class="getClass"
      class="form-input"
      data-vv-validate-on="none"
      v-on="{
        ...$listeners,
        input: event => $emit('input', event.target.value)
      }">
  </div>
</template>
```

After modification of my code (**v-on** above) I got this

#### Object spread operator requires specified objectAssign option with 'Object.assign' or polyfill helper.

```
Summary of all failing tests
 FAIL  src/apps/common/components/tables/reports-table.unit.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Object spread operator requires specified objectAssign option with 'Object.assign' or polyfill helper. (1:412)

      at Node.transpile (node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:12676:11)
      at node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:5864:59
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Node.transpile (node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:5864:10)
      at Node.transpile (node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:6553:28)
      at node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:5864:59
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Node.transpile (node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:5864:10)
      at Node.transpile (node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:6553:28)
```

#### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "jsx-vue-functional",
    "transform-vue-jsx",
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-es2015-destructuring",
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2", "jest"],
      "plugins": [
        "transform-vue-jsx",
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
        "dynamic-import-node",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-es2015-destructuring",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

#### build/vue-loader.conf.js

```
'use strict'
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const sourceMapEnabled = isProduction
  ? config.build.productionSourceMap
  : config.dev.cssSourceMap

module.exports = {
  loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
    sourceMap: sourceMapEnabled,
    extract: isProduction
  }),
  cssSourceMap: sourceMapEnabled,
  cacheBusting: config.dev.cacheBusting,
  transformToRequire: {
    video: ['src', 'poster'],
    source: 'src',
    img: 'src',
    image: 'xlink:href'
  },
  buble: {
    objectAssign: 'Object.assign'
  }
}
```

**
I already have stage-2 and transform-object-rest-spread in my .babelrc**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jest error Unexpected token ... (ES6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893494/jest-error-unexpected-token-es6)

Comment: @Derek my babelrc has stage-2 and transform-object-rest-spread but still errors. Something with bubble.js that vue is using under the hood.

Comment: Show me where exactly you're using the spread operator. Is it in a component?

Comment: Added in the question copy of my code.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)